# How to save data in NSUserDefaults even if app will be deleted?

Tags: iphone, save, nsuserdefaults

I save some strings and numbers to NSUSerDefault,
but when I uninstall and reinstall the app the data is ereased.

Is there a possibility to store data some where else? Maybe in keychain?

Answer (score 2):

There are two places where you can store data that will persist after an app is deleted, but in both cases, it's not hidden data, so if that's what you're looking for, you're out of luck.

Your two possibilities are 1) Saving data to the photo library.  (However, you can't read it back unless you get the user to select the photo for you.)  2) The address book.  This is one place where you can create an entry and select it without user input.

Comment: for iOS 4 & 5, there is 1 more option: Calendar.

Comment: For IOS 5+ there's also iCloud, for any ios- any other webservice- you can just save data for userID and redownload if user reinstalls your app (what is more, you could do it on any other device user has - ipad/mac/pc/android etc). Still the idea to save data on device when app is uninstalled is crazy for me- it would be very bad user experience.

Answer (score 1):

You could stash a small amount of data in the comments field of a keychain record.

However, I doubt Apple would allow it because it would violate the principle of sandboxing the apps. It's hard to think of a legitimate reason to have an app leave data behind after it's gone.

Comment: There are some in-app purchase cases where you'd like to make sure that content remains unlocked if a user accidentally deletes the application from their device.

Comment: that's why apple wants a "restore purchases" button in every app with iap.